# How can I calculate current position of planet in sky

Tags: planet, planetary-science, planetary-transits

How can I calculate current position of planet in sky from earth's point of view. I want to calculate based on given DATETIME and Location

For example, if I see current position of planets on "23 Jan 2024 22:46:28" From Location India,
Sun    Capricorn   08° 59' 37" and
Saturn Aquarius    11° 19' 11"

I tried to search online but unable to understand if am referring to the correct content. Are there any algorithms which I can learn and implement that in Python scripting.

Comment: It's a lot of work if you want high precision, especially for the Moon. But a good place to start is https://stjarnhimlen.se/comp/ppcomp.html which has algorithms & a turorial. Also see https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/planets/approx_pos.html

Comment: You have to look for ephemeris calculation (plural ephemerides). There are entire books on that. Looking for python code, start with astropy.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use existing code, or some online service? BTW, it looks like you're using Indian ecliptic coordinates, which are roughly 23° behind Western coordinates. But that's just a minor issue.

Comment: One popular algorithm is VSOP87, implementations in multiple languages are here: https://github.com/gmiller123456/vsop87-multilang

Comment: Paul Schlyter has also updated webpage with worked examples: https://stjarnhimlen.se/comp/tutorial.html

Comment: @Leos I linked to Paul Schlyter's stuff earlier.

Comment: I know. I linked to his better webpage (worked examples are invaluable).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! i will go though and work on it..

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, am searching Indian ecliptic coordinates...that's why I was unable to understand content on few websites. I also tried some of their calculations on paper